# Hive XML Serde - boolean xpath doesn't parse

Tags: xml, hive, hive-serde

I'm creating a simple hive table using [this](https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-XML-SerDe) XML Serde, but it's throwing an exception when trying to parse the XPath below.

I've tried to use the VTD and Javax processor for the following xpath:
`column.xpath.is_application=/Msg/Header/Type='APP'`
but it throws the following exception:

**VTD:**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ximpleware.XPathEvalException: BinaryExpr can't eval to a node set!

**Javax.xml:**

> Caused by: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathException: Can not convert #BOOLEAN to a NodeList!

**Example XML Doc**

```
<Msg>
  <Header>
     <Type>APP</Type>
  </Header>
</Msg>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be that you want `/Msg/Header[Type='APP']`?

Comment: @Tomalak no but to be clear I've added an example XML doc

Comment: The error clearly says *"BinaryExpr can't eval to a node set"* so it expects a node set and not `true()` or `false()`.

Comment: yes I agree, but I was hoping someone who has used this serde can tell me how they would go about getting the value of true/false (which may mean changing the xpath or maybe a property on the Hive CREATE TABLE statement) or that it's not supported and other potential workarounds. I couldn't see any references to it in the documentation.